# expected dimension but got

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, sdk, vm-implementation

this message appeared. as resolver: AAPT: error: expected dimension but got (raw string) match_parent.

here is my build:
`dependencies { implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1' implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1' implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0' implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4' testImplementation 'junit:junit:' androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5' androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1' implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0") }`

Here the error line:`</style>        <style name="Theme.DiskPizzaCascavel.TxtInformationBase">            <item name="android:width">match_parent</item>            <item name="android:height">wrap_content</item>        </style>`

`'I changed the sdk to 33, I changed the implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0', then to the implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0' but it still didn't work. I really don't know what's wrong.`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to define the layout attributes:

```
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item> 
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item> 
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
```

Comment: I don't believe I had this problem and I didn't see it. thanks.
now I have this: annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.  can tell me. I'm starting and I'm full of errors, I don't know how to deal with it, gradle, versions, dependencies.